# What is the equivalent of Batch file syntax (*.* or *.csv) for python?

Tags: python, file, batch-file, directory, suffix

I am trying to open a file with python where the filename is 2018_01_25_(filename).csv.

In batch files i used C:*.csv to open the csv file. I have tried this in python 2.7 but it doesnt work.

a = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
i want to use, a = pd.read_csv("*.csv")
Is there a python equivalent to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36416258/3922132

Comment: See glob module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a one-liner for this, but you can get around it with the `os` package.

```
 import os
 for f in os.scandir():
      if '.csv' == f[-4:]:
           a = pd.read_csv(f)
           break
```

This code will read the first .csv file into `a`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly!